# Surrounding Events in KQL or Matching on Multiple Conditions

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-sentinel

Coming from a ELK background, Kibana had some nice functionality where you could view surrounding events of any record you wished https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover-document-context.html, i.e. view the 5 preceding and 5 proceeding events.

Does something like this exist in the Kusto Query Language?

**Edit:** I should also mention the requirement for this as I realise it might exist, but within a different form.

I'm looking to find several events that need to have **all** occurred during a specific time period, i.e. the previous 5 minutes.

Example; if EventID's 1, 2 and 3 show, I'm not interested. However, if 1, 2, 3 *and* 4 show (within X minutes of each other) then I would like my query to pick this up.

Any hints or tips are appreciated.

Comment: every 5 minutes or just the previous 5 minutes(like now - 5minutes)?

Comment: Currently the only way to achieve such functionality is a complex/inefficient query with multiple self joins. There's a new operator for scanning rows with custom logic that is expected in an upcoming KQL release which should make such scenarios much easier to query.

Comment: @IvanYang the query would need to see events within a 5 minute radius of the relevant event ID's being seen. For example, if event 2 is seen, check the surrounding 5 minutes of the event to see if ID's 1, 3 and 4 are also present.

Comment: @RoyO very useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Time Window Join` is what I needed - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/join-timewindow